# Django admin bulk delete exclude certain queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a multiple objects of a `File` model.

I am trying filter and delete these files based on a certain condition but am failing to succeed in this.

#### Consider the following

I have 3 `File` objects:

- File1
- File2
- File3

I tried to override the `delete()` function of the model like this:

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    test_qs = File.objects.filter(file_name='File1')
    if test_qs:
        for x in test_qs:
            x.delete()
    super(File, self).delete()
```

When I go to my Django Admin, select all the files (File1, File2 & File3) and bulk delete them, all of them are deleted instead of just File1.

In my Django Console `File.objects.filter(file_name='File1')` returns a queryset with just File1.

I also tried to override the `pre_delete` signal like this:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=File)
def delete_certain_files(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    test_qs = File.objects.filter(file_name='File1')
    test_qs.delete()
```

This however, results in a `RecursionError`

How do I make sure to just delete the `File` objects that meet a certain condition upon bulk deletion?

Comment: Why you want to use Django signal here ? (This is why RecursionError exception is raised). Just filter and then delete, what's problem ?
Also, you do not need model-level override of delete.

Comment: In my Django Admin when an user selected all the Files and does a bulk delete, I want to only delete the Files that meet a certain condition and keep the rest.

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it helps you. good luck !

Comment: Your answer + reading the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_queryset) helped me solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Hope to listen this. Good luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, If you want this on admin. Imagine we have `Foo` model and `FooAdmin` class

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    actions = ['delete_selected']

    def delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        # request: WSGIRrequest
        # queryset: QuerySet, this is used for deletion
        lookup_kwargs = {'pk__gt': 5000} # you can add your own condition.
        queryset.filter(**lookup_kwargs)

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```